# Not able to uninstall MiKTeX after an interrupted deinstallation

Tags: errors, installing, miktex2.9

I have unfortunately interrupted the uninstallation process and now I am not able to deinstall the MiKteX from my computer. I get the following message:
[image]

I went to the C directory and deleted all the MiKteX files and tried to install it again. But at the end, it was not successful and I have received the following error.
[image]

I also got a log file reporting the problem. 
I could post this if it helps seeing it.

I would be really glad, if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Reboot the computer. Try to restart the deinstallation. Result?

Comment: Just delete the entire MiKTeX 2.9 folder, reinstall and hope for the best.  (I've done this many times, and only once had to fix the resulting registry.)

Comment: I tried both strategies. Unfortunately these were also uncessessful. Here is the last part of the log file with the errors when I tried to reinstall: 
Registering root directories...
78 [0x0000162c] FATAL initexmf null - Windows API error 5: Zugriff verweigert
78 [0x0000162c] FATAL initexmf null - Info: path="Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\Core"
78 [0x0000162c] FATAL initexmf null - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winRegistry.cpp
78 [0x0000162c] FATAL initexmf null - Line: 173
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

Comment: well something is denying miktex a permission. Do you have some agressive virus protection or something like this?